# Angular location service is not changing path

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to execute `$location.path(path)` from within my code but when I check in my browser I see that the url changes for a millisecond or so and comes back to the previous url, hence my page doesn't change.

Any idea?

Comment: I got it working, I needed to set `reloadOnSearch` to `true` to make it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I also had that problem with an anchor defined like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="bookToday()">book today!</a>
```

It turns out that the hash (`#`) in the `href` attribute caused the app to loop back to the default route all the time.

I changed the link by removing the hash, and then it worked:

```
<a href="" ng-click="bookToday()">book today!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$location.path()`  is a getter function to set you need to call `$location.path('/yourpath')`

Comment: Also make sure that the location path is valid and defined in your routes, else it would redirect back to the default path

Comment: ya! I have corrected that it was a typo. Also, `path` is a relative or absolute value here?

Comment: show a bit more code so we can have a context as to where you're calling this from etc